# MySQL querying result where JSON encoded data is LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

Until I get a chance to go through and store this data another way, some of my data is stored as JSON encoded arrays. I need to perform a query against this data:

```
$query = 'jones';

$inv = $db->select("
  SELECT ID, OrderData FROM store_orders 
  WHERE ShippingData LIKE '%$query%' LIMIT 5");
```

The contents of `ShippingData` would look like:

```
{"ShippingFirstName":"Bob","ShippingLastName":"Jones","ShippingAddress":"123 Main St","ShippingAddress2":"Apt B","ShippingCity":"Mytown","ShippingState":"FL","ShippingZip":"12345","ShippingCountry":"US","ShippingPhone":"","ShippingEmail":"my@email.com"}
```

I am trying to minimize false positive results by performing the query only against the `ShippingLastName` field. I tried:

```
$inv = $db->select("
  SELECT ID, OrderData FROM store_orders 
  WHERE ShippingData LIKE '\"ShippingLastName\":\"%$query%\"' LIMIT 5"); // Escaping double quotes
```

Only this did not return any results. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have missing wildcards `%` around your condition. Something like : `LIKE '%\"ShippingLastName\":\"%$query%\"%' LIMIT 5`. I am not sure we can use so much `%` characters in a query but that's worth a try.

Comment: so ShippingData is storing JSON?

Comment: @Mat Awesome! That's all I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are missing wildcards around the `WHERE` condition. It should be like this  :

`SELECT ID, OrderData FROM store_orders 
 WHERE ShippingData LIKE '%\"ShippingLastName\":\"%$query%\"%' LIMIT 5`

You can add as many wildcard `%` character with the like operator. Documentation here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

You may also try this syntax for more readability (escape double quotes)

`SELECT ID, OrderData FROM store_orders 
 WHERE ShippingData LIKE '%"ShippingLastName":"%$query%"%' ESCAPE '"' LIMIT 5`

Comment: this will return a false positive match if `$query` appears anywhere after `ShippingLastName` like in the `ShippingAddress` field.

Answer (score 0):

You need a to surround the entire pattern with wildcards `%`.  No need to include or escape the quotation marks.  This should do it:

```
$inv = $db->select("
    SELECT ID, OrderData FROM store_orders 
    WHERE ShippingData LIKE '%ShippingLastName___$query%' LIMIT 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from @Mat, here is the answer. I did not have wildcards at the beginning and end:

```
$inv = $db->select("
  SELECT ID, OrderData FROM store_orders 
  WHERE ShippingData LIKE '%\"ShippingLastName\":\"%$query%\"%' LIMIT 5"); // Escaping double quotes
```

Now, this works perfectly.

Comment: Was in the process of writing my answer when that was added as a comment - just want to note that all those escaped quotes and such are really not necessary.